# How to read multiple result sets returned from a SQL Server stored procedure in R

Tags: sql-server, r

How do I capture multiple tables returned from a stored procedure call?

```
conn<- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=server;database=db;trusted_connection=yes')
data <- sqlQuery(conn,paste("exec dbo.GetTest"),errors=FALSE)
```

It only captures the first table returned in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RODBC may not have a feature to retrieve multiple recordsets from a stored procedure. However, Windows ADO does have the [NextRecordSet()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677539(v=vs.85).aspx) method. Consider having R make a COM interface call to ADO using the `RDCOMClient` library (assuming of course you use R for Windows). In ADO's connection object, you pass the same connection string as you did in RODBC.

Below retrieves query results with ADO's [GetRows()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx) which returns a two-dimensional array translated as nested lists in R.

**SQL Server** *(Stored Proc)*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MultipleResults 
AS    
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM Table1;
    SELECT * FROM Table2;
END
```

**R** *(ADO Call)*

```
library(RDCOMClient)

conn <- COMCreate("ADODB.Connection")
rst <- COMCreate("ADODB.Recordset")

conn$Open("driver={SQL Server};server=server;database=db;trusted_connection=yes;")

# FIRST QUERY RESULT
rst$Open("MultipleResults", conn)
dfList1 <- rst$GetRows()    
# RETRIEVE COLUMN NAMES
dfnames1 <- vapply(c(0:(rst[['Fields']]$Count()-1)), 
                   function(i) (rst$Fields(i)$Name()), character(1))

# SECOND QUERY RESULT
rst <- rst$NextRecordset()
dfList2 <- rst$GetRows()    
# RETRIEVE COLUMN NAMES
dfnames2 <- vapply(c(0:(rst[['Fields']]$Count()-1)), 
                   function(i) (rst$Fields(i)$Name()), character(1))   
# CLOSE OBJECTS
rst$Close(); conn$Close()

# FREE RESOURCES
rst <-  conn <- NULL
rm(rst, conn)
gc()

# CONVERT NESTED LISTS TO DATAFRAMES    
dfList1 <- lapply(dfList1, function(x) setNames(data.frame(x), dfnames1))    
df1 <- do.call(rbind, dfList1)

dfList2 <- lapply(dfList2, function(x) setNames(data.frame(x), dfnames2))      
df2 <- do.call(rbind, dfList2)
```